# IIS 7.5, cannot point to the correct web site

Tags: iis-7.5, amazon-web-services

I create a windows instance on aws ec2.  its windows sever 2008 r2 with IIS 7.5 installed.

I went to IIS, add another web site there. however, my domain name still connect to the "Default Web Site", not the one I just added.

I also changed the Host file , add this line there.
23.21.186.205 www.smartmoki.com

still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a host header to the new web site.

Also, you should remove the entry you added to the host file as it's got nothing to do with your issue.